# Question about my approach to linear algebra proof, Axler Ch.2A #14

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I need some help verifying my approach because the answers that I found online use a different approach.

**Problem statement:**

Prove that a vector space V is infinite-dimensional if and only if there is a sequence of vectors $v_1, v_2, ...$ in $V$ such that $v_1,..,v_m$ is linearly independent for every positive integer $m$.

**Forward direction.**

Premise: Suppose $V$ is infinite-dimensional.
We want to show that a linearly independent list of vectors $v_1,..,v_m$ exists for every positive integer $m$.

Proof by contradiction.

Suppose no linearly independent list exists for some list of $m$ vectors. This implies that the spanning list is less than $m$. To see this, consider that a list of vectors will always be dependent if and only if the size of the list is greater than a linearly independent list that also spans the vector space.

So, there is some list size $<m$ that spans V. This contradicts the original premise that V is infinite dimensional. Therefore, a linearly independent list must exist for every positive integer $m$.

**Reverse direction.**

Premise: Suppose a linearly independent list exists for some $v_1,..,v_m$ for every positive integer $m$. We want to show that $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Proof by contradiction.

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Then, suppose some arbitrary list of vectors of size $m-1$ spans this finite-dimensional $V$. But, $v_1,..,v_m$ must be a linearly independent list also exists in $V$ according to our premise. A spanning list cannot be less than the length of a linearly independent list. So, $V$ must be infinite dimensional.

Therefore, a vector space $V$ is infinite dimensional if and only if there is a sequence of vectors $v_1, v_2, ...$ in $V$ such that $v_1,..,v_m$ is linearly independent for every positive integer $m$.

Thanks.

Comment: In your proof of the reverse direction, you might want to assume the finite dimension of $V$ is $n.$ No list of more than $n$ vectors can be linearly independent in $V$, which contradicts your premise.

Comment: The above comment by Chris (+1) follows my own general critique (see answer below) that you need to **instantiate the objects you use**: Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional, **then there is a positive integer $n$ and a list of vectors $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ such that $Span\{v_1, ..., v_n\}=V$**. You see, now we have instantiated an explicit integer $n$ and explicit vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ that we can talk about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some running comments in your first proof:

```
Premise: Suppose  is infinite-dimensional. 
We want to show that a linearly independent 
list of vectors _1,..,v_ exists for every 
positive integer .
```

Good and clear premise.

```
Proof by contradiction.
Suppose no linearly independent list exists for some list of  vectors.
```

No, the contradiction should not start by assuming you have a list of $m$ vectors. It should start by assuming you have a positive integer $m$ for which no linearly independent list of $m$ vectors exists.

```
 This implies that the spanning list is less than
```

What do you mean by "the spanning list"? What spanning list?  Spanning list of what?

```
To see this, consider that a list of 
vectors will always be dependent if and 
only if the size of the list is greater 
than a linearly independent list that 
also spans the vector space.
```

The "if and only if" is incorrect.  You are trying to state the general fact that **if (but not only if)** a collection of vectors is larger than a collection of vectors that span the space, then the first collection cannot be linearly independent.  However, while that is a general fact, you have not set up your proof in a way that clearly makes use of this fact.  What list/lists are you talking about? You have not fixed any list, you only make vague claims about nonexistence of a list. You need to **instantiate** the objects you use with phrases such as "let xyz be a pdq with property abc" or "There exists an object abc with property xyz."

```
So, there is some list size m
that spans V.
```

How do you conclude this?

```
This contradicts 
the original premise that V is infinite 
dimensional. Therefore, a linearly 
independent list must exist for every 
positive integer .
To see this, consider that a list of 
vectors will always be dependent if 
and only if the size of the list is 
greater than a linearly independent 
list that also spans the vector space.
```

Comment: While the premise is clear, a higher-level critique wonders if the premise is sufficient for the forward direction: It seems the question asks for a single infinite sequence $\{v_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ rather than a finite set of vectors that exists for each $m$ (which might use completely different vectors for each $m$, i.e., $m=2$ list is $\{v_1,v_2\}$; $m=3$ list is $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$, ...).

Comment: It may be better to change your premise/approach: Try recursively building your list $\{v_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$: Let $v_1$ be any nonzero vector in $V$.  Now form $v_2$. In general you start with $\{v_1, ..., v_k\}$ and then find another $v_{k+1}$.

Comment: For the forward direction, I want to state the fact that an arbitrary collection of vectors will always be dependent if and only if that arbitrary collection of vectors has a size greater than another collection of vectors that is both linearly independent and spans the vector space $V$. Since that linearly independent set spans $V$, it contradicts the premise that $V$ is infinite-dimensional. Point taken about instantiation!

Comment: The "if and only if" regarding the size of your list is incorrect: The vectors $\{(0,0,1), (0,0,2)\}$ are linearly dependent but $\{(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0)\}$ are linearly independent. You  want to use **if** rather than **if and only if**.

Comment: So I mean to say that any list of vectors with length greater than 3 in $R^3$ will necessarily be linearly dependent (Any list in the set of all lists of vectors greater than 3 in $R^3$ is linearly dependent). In your example, while a list of vectors length 2 can be linearly dependent, it is not always linearly dependent (i.e. there is a linearly independent list of length 2 as well). Is the if and only if true in that sense?

Comment: You can engineer an "if and only if" statement but I do not think the statement is particularly useful in this case: Let $n$ be a positive integer and suppose there are vectors $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ that span a vector space $V$.  Let $m$ be a positive integer.  Then $m>n$ **if and only if** every collection of $m$ vectors in $V$ is linearly dependent.  [The useful direction is the statement "If $m>n$ then every collection of $m$ vectors in $V$ is linearly dependent."]